# How to Delay a image animation after game load

Tags: ios, animation

I need to find an option to delay the animation on this object (cloudDrop2 image). All time when I load the game, the cloudDrop2 image shows going down. I want to delay the animation for 5 seconds after load the game. After 5 second then the image shows going down. I'm using Xcode 5.

Any Help or suggestions?

Here's the code what I'm using:

on .m file

```
-(void)cloudDrop2Code{

// cloudDrop2 Images Animation
cloudDrop2.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"cloudDrop2.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"cloudDrop1.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"cloudDrop2.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"cloudDrop1.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"cloudDrop2.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"cloudDrop1.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"cloudDrop2.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"cloudDrop1.png"],nil];

[cloudDrop2 setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
cloudDrop2.animationDuration = 0.1;
[cloudDrop2 startAnimating];

// Drop Cloud Ramdom Position

cloudDrop2.center = CGPointMake(cloudDrop2.center.x, cloudDrop2.center.y +2.1);
if (cloudDrop2.center.y > 590){

    RamdomPosition = arc4random() %266;
    RamdomPosition = RamdomPosition +54;

    cloudDrop2.center = CGPointMake(RamdomPosition, -40);
    dropCloudUsed = NO;


    // Time to Drop Cloud Down Again
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:7.0]];

}
```

}

Then in `viewDidLoad` method:

```
// cloudDrop2 Down Movement Speed
TMcloudDrop2 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.03 
                        target:self 
                        selector:@selector(cloudDrop2Code)
                        userInfo:nil 
                        repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your timer in a separate method.

```
- (void)startGameAnimation
{
  // cloudDrop2 Down Movement Speed
TMcloudDrop2 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.03 
                        target:self 
                        selector:@selector(cloudDrop2Code)
                        userInfo:nil 
                        repeats:YES];
}
```

Then in the `viewDidLoad` call this method with delay.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self performSelector:@selector(startGameAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, Thank You Mustafa Ahmed, Now my game looks very clean also. Thank You for your time.

Comment: What code do you want to run?! The `cloudDrop2Code` method already runs every 0.03 second as you set the timer to repeat.

Comment: In general, you can schedule another timer with time interval set to 18. `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:18 target:self  selector:@selector(cloudDrop2Code) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];`

Comment: Is weird, Is like need to wait all the other animation to show's again. All other animations fall after cloud, but then show's all the images falling at same time. Any Idea or suggestion?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I will try your code today and send you my feedback. If you have a sample project that do what you have problem with, it will save me time.

Comment: Hi Mustafa, I go to wait for your response, Please let me know how can I send you my testing project. Thank You for your help and your time.

Comment: I sent you two email with my .h and .m files. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

I don't see any of the code which is responsible for loading your game parts. You should probably post that as to make it easier to answer your question.

Not seeing any other part of your code, I would suggest you use NSNotification to alert you when the game has finished loading. Once you received your notification, you can start your animation sequence.

You can read up on the [NSNotification Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html). If you need some help or pointers, don't be afraid to ask.

To use a timer delay with 5 seconds for starting your animation you can use this:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
  target:self
selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
userInfo:nil
 repeats:NO];
```

Where (targetMethod:) is the name of your method which contains the animation.

Comment: The -(IBAction) is probably linked to a button on the screen and is the code that runs when the button is tapped. The viewDidLoad is probably where the first part of your game loading starts. If you are learning, I suggest you experiment a bit. Start adding the NSNotification in the viewDidLoad and see what happens. If you don't get the results you want, then try the IBAction.

Comment: @HEMAN85 - I have updated the answer to include a 5 sec timer.